# How to make two blocks of radio buttons with the same name to be separated blocks in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use two blocks of radio buttons for my project in which I'm storing the values in the Database and I'm showing one radio buttons block or the other depending on another result in the HTML form.

The problem is if I use the same name for all the options they are all part of the same group, which I don't want.

I just want to give it a try and ask if there's a way to group it in different blocks with the same name, is this even possible?

This is my [sample code in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdLwjqe0/)

And mi code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
    <legend>Negotiated:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="0" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-view-a">No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="1" />
    <label for="radio-view-b">Yes</label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
    <legend>Negotiated:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a1" value="0" />
    <label for="radio-view-a1">No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b1" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-view-b1">Yes</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: its not possible to use same names. you need to give different names to different groups.

Comment: Instead of giving them same `id`, you can give them same `class`. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp for reference.

Comment: you're most welcome @SaulOrtega :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can easily be solved, if you give them same classes. Change your code to this :

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
<legend>Negotiated:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="radio-view1" class="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="0" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio-view-a">No</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-view1" class="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="1" />
<label for="radio-view-b">Yes</label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
<legend>Negotiated:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="radio-view2" class="radio-view" id="radio-view-a1" value="0" />
<label for="radio-view-a1">No</label>
<input type="radio" name = "radio-view2" class="radio-view" id="radio-view-b1" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio-view-b1">Yes</label>
</fieldset>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsbeginner/sdLwjqe0/2/)

Or if for some reason you don't want to use `class` then you can use `data-customclass` attribute, your code will look like this :

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
<legend>Negotiated:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="radio-view1" data-customclass="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="0" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio-view-a">No</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-view1" data-customclass="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="1" />
<label for="radio-view-b">Yes</label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
<legend>Negotiated:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="radio-view2" data-customclass="radio-view" id="radio-view-a1" value="0" />
<label for="radio-view-a1">No</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-view2" data-customclass="radio-view" id="radio-view-b1" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio-view-b1">Yes</label>
</fieldset>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsbeginner/sdLwjqe0/3/)

> In the second approach, you can use any attribute prefixed with `data-`. For example, you can also use `data-myclass`.
>
> But don't include uppercase letters,they are not allowed. If you are using any framework such as `jQuery Mobile` then don't use its reserved `data-` attributes such as `data-role`. Prefixing your attribute with 'my' is a good practice, for example, `data-myclass`.

Comment: the name is different in each group. radio-view1 and radio-view2

Comment: @SaulOrtega The names can not be the same. If I didn't misunderstand, you want to give all the form elements an identification, so that you can refer to them in JavaScript. This can be done with classes also. Just use `document.getElementsByClassName("radio-view");`. I really don't see any other reason for giving all elements the same `name`, and if there is another reason then please let me know. And if there isn't then I think you should accept this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Arjun, but what I need is to have them with the same name so when I put their values into their database. The platform that Im using is going to be looking for the element with that specific name, if it has a different name it will try to put it in another field in the DB which I don't want.

Comment: @SaulOrtega Unfortunately, as far as I know, this is not possible. I am sorry  that I could and can not help you.

Comment: @SaulOrtega I hope someone else will help you out.

Comment: I'm givign you a vote up because you tried to help me thanks!